# Не могу ввести символ в поле ввода но пост добавляет

Tags: reactjs

```
    import './index.css';
    import React from 'react';
    import store from './redux/redux-store';
    import { RouterProvider } from 'react-router';
    import {router} from './Router';
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
    
     let rerenderEntireTree=(state) =>{
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
        root.render(
          <React.StrictMode>
           <RouterProvider  router = {router}  dispatch={store.dispatch.bind(store)} store={store} state={state}/>;
         </React.StrictMode>
        );
        
      }
    rerenderEntireTree(store.getState());
    
    store.substribe(() => {
      let state=store.getState();
      rerenderEntireTree(state);
    });
    ServiceWorker.unregister();
    
    import Music from './componens/Music/Music';
    import Roote from './Roote';
    import News from './componens/News/News';
    import Clasik from "./componens/Music/Clasik";
    import Dialogs from "./componens/Dialogs/Dialogs";
    import Profili from "./componens/Profili/Profili";
    import store from "./redux/redux-store";
    import {
      createBrowserRouter
    
    } from "react-router-dom";
    
    
    export const router = createBrowserRouter([    
      {
        path: "/",
      element:<Roote state={store.getState()} 
      dispatch={store.dispatch.bind(store)} />,
        
       children: [
          {
            path: "dialogs",
            element: <Dialogs state={store.getState()} 
            dispatch={store.dispatch.bind(store)}/>,
          },
          {
            path: "news",
            element: <News />,
          },
          {
            path: "music",
            element: <Music />,
          },
              {
                path: "music/clasik",
                element: <Clasik />,
              },
            
          
          {
            path: "profili",
            element: <Profili 
           profilePage={store.getState().profili.newPostText}
            dispatch={store.dispatch.bind(store)}
            state={store.getState()}
             />,
            
          },
        ],
      },
      
    ]);
    
    
   
  import s from '../Dialogs/Dialogs.module.css';
import DialogsItem from './DialogsItem/DialogsItem';
import Messange from './Message/Message';
import React from 'react';
import {addDialogActionnCreator ,updaNewDialogTexstActionnCreator  } from '../../redux/dialogs-reducer';


const Dialogs = (props) =>{

let newDialogElement = React.createRef();

    let addDialog = () => {
       props.dispatch(addDialogActionnCreator());
      
        
    };
    let onDialogChange = () => {

        let text = newDialogElement.current.value;
        props.dispatch(updaNewDialogTexstActionnCreator(text));
    };

    let DialodsElements = props.state.dialogs.DialogsData.map(d => <DialogsItem name={d.name} id={d.id} />);
    let MessagesElements = props.state.dialogs.Messages.map(d => <Messange message={d.message} ad={d.ad} />);
    return (
        <div className={s.dialogs}>
            <div className={s.dialogsItem}>

                {DialodsElements}

            </div>
            <div className={s.messages}>
                {MessagesElements}
            </div>
            <div className={s.button}>
                <div><textarea onChange={onDialogChange} ref={newDialogElement} 
                value={props.state.dialogs.newDialogtext} /></div>
                <div><button onClick={addDialog}>Add post</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
};
export default Dialogs;
```